# What is the signature of mainCRTStartup

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi, entry-point

I am looking for the signature of mainCRTStartup. Is it :

```
int mainCRTStartup( int argc, char *argv[] )
```

Or something else ?

I find it so irritating that microsoft isn't even able to give the définition of their own entry points...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dumb answer, my question is pretty clear and straight forward : what is the signature of mainCRTStartup. I don't see what's ambiguous or whatever in this sentence.

Comment: So look at the CRT directory.

Comment: It's definitely not `char *argv[]`; in Windows, the command line is one flat string which programs have to tokenize themselves.  CRT code has to do that before calling main.  Unlike Unix where process args are an array of strings (from the `execve` system call).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `crtexe.c` file, distributed with VisualStudio, you can see the definition. It is:

```
int mainCRTStartup(void);
```

The command line is not obtained as an argument to the entry point, but recovered by using the function `GetCommandLine()`.